# Accessing Twitter's API via OAuth1 in Node results in 401

Tags: twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am attempting to post a tweet to Twitter from my NodeJS code (Lambda function). Using all my tokens in Postman, it works, the tweet goes. I've never used OAuth1 from Node before, and most references I'm finding online ate many years old using deprecated libraries (i.e. `request`)

Here's my code

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');
const crypto = require('crypto');

...
const oauth = OAuth({
  consumer: {
      key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  },
  signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
  hash_function(base_string, key) {
      return crypto
          .createHmac('sha1', key)
          .update(base_string)
          .digest('base64')
  },
})

const request_data = {
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets',
  method: 'POST',
  data: { text: 'Hello World!' },
}

const token = {
  key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

const auth = oauth.authorize(request_data, token)

console.log('tweeting')
console.log(JSON.stringify(oauth.toHeader(auth)))
const tweetResp = await fetch(request_data.url, {
  method: request_data.method,
  body: request_data.data,
  headers: {
    ...oauth.toHeader(auth),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
if (tweetResp.status !== 200) {
  console.error('returned status', tweetResp.status, tweetResp.statusText)
  const postedTweet = await tweetResp.json()
  console.error(JSON.stringify(postedTweet))
  throw JSON.stringify(postedTweet)
}
console.log('tweet sent')
```

my logging output shows

```
INFO    tweeting
INFO    {"Authorization":"OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_nonce=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxx%xx\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1672968399\", oauth_token=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""}
ERROR   returned status 401 Unauthorized
ERROR   {"title":"Unauthorized","type":"about:blank","status":401,"detail":"Unauthorized"}
```

If I remove the `...oauth.toHeader(auth),` line from `headers` I get the same errors. I've also tried the `got` library, getting same 401 back...

Answer (score 0):

Further googling and I found this [functional code](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/0d1587147d3bf8338b5fea2b4e5bb56d37f5c2b6/Manage-Tweets/create_tweet.js#L91)! This works great

```js
async function getRequest({
  oauth_token,
  oauth_token_secret
}) {

  const token = {
    key: oauth_token,
    secret: oauth_token_secret
  };

  const authHeader = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize({
    url: endpointURL,
    method: 'POST'
  }, token));

  const req = await got.post(endpointURL, {
    json: data,
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: authHeader["Authorization"],
      'user-agent': "v2CreateTweetJS",
      'content-type': "application/json",
      'accept': "application/json"
    }
  });
  if (req.body) {
    return req.body;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Unsuccessful request');
  }
}
```